# Parent Directory does not allow write permission to the process

Tags: linux, openfoam

I am trying to create a mesh using openFoam and blockMesh, but when I use blockMesh in the project directory I get:

```
The parent directory does not allow write permission to the process, or one of the directories in ~/icoFoa,/cavity/cavity/constant/polyMesh did not allow search (exacute) permission.
```

Why isnt blockMesh wokring?

Comment: Can you share the code about what you tried so that we know whats the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by changing the permissions of each file that I run the simulation in. Maybe there is a smarter answer but this is what worked for me. Also I run the simulation not in /opt but /home. The commands I used are:

```
sudo chmod 777 cavity/ %simulation file name
sudo chmod 777 0/
sudo chmod 777 constant/
sudo chmod 777 system/
```